Revisiting how to repair broken JPEG images?
This has come up a number of times. This post here shows a way to extract the thumbnails:

How to repair corrupted JPEG files that still have their thumbnails (AskUbuntu)

That's a low-res solution, though. It's not really repairing anything.
I propose that if a broken or damaged JPEG is encountered, that these steps seem reasonable:

Extract the thumbnail (if available) before making other changes.
Use convert (ImageMagick) to try to recover it.
Use jpegrepair (see comments) to try to recover it.
Use xxd or hexedit to try to manually repair it, though I'm trying to figure out if there is a more deterministic way to tell whether a file is fixable or unrecoverably damaged before going to this level of effort.

Now my question is this: Is there a way to determine with confidence whether a JPEG file is a definitely unrecoverable file?

JPEG is a compressed format. Like Zip, redundancy has been largely removed to shrink file size. With a bitmap image, missing a few kB might mean loss of a few thousand pixels -- but with compressed images, loss of even a few bytes effectively makes it unusable.

@JoepvanSteen You're not wrong, though the kinds of answers I was looking for are here in these comments.  The 'jpegrepair' tool looks like it's worth looking into.
DrMoishePippik 's response is also part of what I was looking for.  It answers the (also rather open-ended) question, "Is this a solvable problem?"  This tells me that, in some cases, the data is quite simply lost and unrecoverable.

@JoepvanSteen edited the original post for more clarity and to make it a little less open-ended, especially where the initial diagnosis is concerned.

"… but hardly guaranteed" – How can any tool guarantee anything in case of a corrupted file? In general the file may be arbitrarily corrupted. There is always a limit to how much you can recover. If the data is no longer there, no backup, no redundancy, then there is nothing you can do.

@KamilMaciorowski Of course.  Read further down.  If anything, I'm looking for information the other way.  Is there a way to determine that the file is definitely corrupt beyond repair, based on certain data that's missing, for example, that essentially renders the rest of the file worthless?  Like a file that was encrypted using a public key and the private key is lost.  That data is now gone for all reasonable intents and purposes.

It's just as well.  The reason the Python script didn't work had to do with using a Python interpreter that was too old.  Using a newer Python installation allowed the script to work... though it doesn't work very well.  Its guesses are poor and it sometimes "repairs" things that aren't broken.
